# Is there any book or reference that explains evolutionary dynamics and fixation probability?

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny, genetics, population-genetics

I am a master's student in computational and mathematical biology, with a bachelor's degree in pure mathematics.
I am really struggling with my computational biology course, we are supposed to study problems related to evolutionary dynamics like:
1)the rock-paper-scissors game which explains the evolution of male mating strategies in side-blotched lizards
2)fixation probability of a new mutation.
Could someone link me to some books or references that might be helpful in solving such problems?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qdSrAeTNqJRSFYiU335EK4oj2mSv97Id/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

- Maynard Smith, J. (1989) Evolutionary Genetics. Oxford: Oxford University Press. ISBN 0-19-850231-1
- Maynard Smith, J. and Harper, D. (2003) Animal Signals. Oxford University Press. ISBN 0-19-852685-7[16]

Then perform a PubMed search for ‪[Adam Eyre-Walker](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=Eyre-Walker).

Answer (score 2):

I'm fond of Joe Felsenstein's [book](https://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/pgbook/pgbook.html) on evolutionary genetics as a relatively recent source that presents a lot of these problems at a very simple level for the newer student, and then adds complexity gradually. Page 260 seems relevant.